# Are my systems vulnerable from CVE-2016-5696?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, updates, security

I have a request from my network security colleague to investigate the threat of this CVE for our environment and I'm having a hard time figuring it out. When I look on the CVE tracker for that CVE:
https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-5696.html

It lists the package versions as well as the release versions. Which confuses me. Like it seems to imply that you can run the Trusty source on the Precise OS?

But that's besides the point. Our environment is predominantly Precise servers with a handful of Trusty servers and I need to know if this vulnerability applies to me. Is there a command I can run to determine if I'm using one of these packages that is listed. The package names actually specified in the tracker like "linux-lts-trusty" are not apt-get packages so "apt-cache show" doesn't help.

Comment: It would probably be better to ask things like this on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the package that it refers to `linux-lts-trusty` refers to the kernels images. They are named differently in the repositories. If you do `apt-cache search linux-.* | grep 'trusty'` you will find packages like `linux-image-virtual-lts-trusty` or `linux-image-virtual-lts-wily`. In addition , if you open the launchpad link, git.kernel.org link and others from the CVE report you have there all point that this is Linux kernel vulnerability.

So, for `linux-lts-trusty`, for which Launchpad latest version at the time of me writing this is [3.13.0-93.140-precise1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/3.13.0-93.140~precise1) lists that only for Ubuntu 12.04 fix is needed, for other versions bug DNE(does not exist):

[image]

For `linux-lts-wily` , which is version [4.2.0-42.49-14.04.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-wily/4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1) , only trusty (14.04 ) is at risk. 
[image]

So it really depends on the kernel version you are running. Of course, the best approach would be that your server is upgraded to the latest version, 16.04 LTS , and have newer kernel versions. You didn't provide us with your kernel version so we don't know if you are at risk for this or not.

> It lists the package versions as well as the release versions. Which confuses me. Like it seems to imply that you can run the Trusty source on the Precise OS?

Technically you can run older kernel on newer OS version and vice versa, so yes, that is correct.

#### NOTES:

- Wily Werewolf (15.10) has already reached End of Life and no longer supported. If you are running this version, I **strongly** suggest you upgrade.
- `linux-lts-saucy` kernel version appears that it doesn't have that vulnerability . That's version `3.11.0-26.45-precise1` . I would suggest any 3.11.x version, but this is still not ideal ; newer versions are preferable.
- Tracking `linux` in the tracker for this CVE for a given release will track the *base kernel* shipped in that release. Tracking `linux-lts-*` in the tracker for this CVE will track an HWE kernel, available only in LTS editions which get HWE updates. Until all of them are "released" or "fixed", for all Source packages and all relevant distributions on the Tracker, you are not going to be able to 'avoid' the CVE.

Comment: Just to add, this specific CVE has not been fixed in any releases yet, so upgrading to 16.04 won't help in this case.

Comment: @Serg CentOS 5 is affected by this vulnerability ?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the Ubuntu Security website page for that CVE (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-5696.html). It's saying that *ALL* current Ubuntu versions *except* Ubuntu Touch 15.04 are vulnerable (see the table for the 'linux' package, which is what the kernel packages are generated from).

The other tables for linux-lts-XX are for special kernels, e.g. for the LTS Enablement Stack. These tables say 'DNE' for most versions of Ubuntu because these kernels are specific to only one version, not because those versions of Ubuntu aren't vulernable.

Comment: @happyskeptic It is possible to install various  kernels, even if they carry name of different release.  Hence, per version tables. As for  *ALL* current releases, how would you explain `linux-lts-xenial` table also saying `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus): DNE`

Comment: As I wrote, you've completely misunderstood those tables. The kernel linux-lts-xenail *is not available* on 16.04 (Xenial). This kernel is *only* available as an LTS Enablement kernel for 14.04, which is why it's marked as only needing a fix on 14.04.

The basic misunderstanding is you think that 'DNE' always means the bug isn't present in that version. But it actually can also mean that the package isn't present in that Ubuntu version, and therefore no fix needs to be made.

Comment: OK, then how do you explain this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23063008/ I have 16.04 and have that package available

Comment: That's a dummy transitional package only used in upgrades from trusty->xenial. It doesn't contain anything at all and so isn't vulnerable to anything!

Comment: I'm typing this on a phone so can't easily copy paste, but you can easily check with apt-cache show on that package. There are also other dummy packages for wily, precise and other releases - none of them mean anything when talking about vulnerabilities because they all contain absolutely nothing!

Comment: @happyskeptic We use metapackages to point to the actual kernel packages behind the scenes; while you're correct they "contain nothing", for every change to the Kernel,  new Kernel binary packages are created, which the metapackages then point to (and stop pointing to the old ones).  For the Security Tracker, you can rely on `linux-lts-xenial` for example in Trusty to point correctly to where it should, as a 'valid determinator' for whether the corresponding kernel packages in a release are "fixed".  (Please do not make destructive edits to posts either, it causes problems)

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't change the fact that you can't escape the vulnerability in Trusty by installing linux-lts-xenial does it? (At least until the fix is released on 27 Aug). This is the point I've been trying to make and which Serg has ignored in his answer. If you have a better way of fixing the misleading info in that answer them please edit it.

Comment: @happyskeptic If you actually bother looking at the tracker, that's not fixed either, so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.  Installing `linux-lts-xenial` (Trusty) or any other kernel wouldn't fix it either until they're *all* patched.  To actively track whether a fix exists in the stock kernel on any given release, you track `linux` on the tracker, for HWE kernels (14.04.4 for instance is an HWE kernel), you track that specific metapackage.  (Strikethroughing an answer just because it's wrong in an edit suggestion, though, is destructive, and not useful)

Comment: If you actually bother reading the comments on this answer, and my answer below, that's exactly the point I've been trying to make!!

Comment: I have read your comments, and your specific points are unclear. in the mean time I made an edit that should cover your last point and similar ones.

Comment: So if you're finished trying to have a go at me and don't want to accept my edits can you please edit the answer by Serg which I've been trying to get corrected for 2 days now!

Comment: My points are very clear when read in context of correcting the original answer, which you didn't. Thanks for correcting the answer but it shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-5696.html does not make it clear which kernel Xenial (16.04LTS) uses. According to xenial-updates this is currently 4.4.0.34.36 which is vulnerable for CVE-2016-5696.

https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/linux.html shows this as well.

Comment: Correct, Xenial (16.04) is vulnerable currently - until Ubuntu release patched kernels for it, which should be by 27 August.

The relevant kernel to look at on that page is 'linux', this is the source package from which all normal (i.e. not specialised LTS Enablement kernels or other once-offs) kernel packages are built.

Comment: It's well possible to switch to other kernel version not affected by this CVE.

Comment: No it isn't. If you're on, for example, 14.04, the only more recent kernel is the LTS Enablement linux-lts-xenial which is affected by the bug. Same if you're on Xenial - there is no more recent kernel. If you're on 12.04 your LTS Enablement kernel is linux-lts-trusty, which is affected.

The only current way to switch to a kernel version not affected is to use the -proposed repo (as suggested by Trent Lloyd), which already contains the fixed kernel that'll be released by 27 Aug.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (16 August 2016) *ALL* current versions of Ubuntu apart from Ubuntu Touch 15.04 are vulnerable:
[image]

The relevant info from Ubuntu is here, they plan on releasing patched kernels by 27 August:
https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-5696.html

As explained in my comment to Serg's answer above, the important package to look at is 'linux', which is the source package for the kernels in each release. The other packages are mostly LTS Enablement kernels or other specialised kernels, all of which are specific to particular versions.

For example linux-lts-quantal is listed as 'DNE' for all versions except 12.04 (which is anyway end-of-life). However this doesn't mean that those versions are not affected by the issue, the 'DNE' is there because the package linux-lts-quantal was only ever specific to 12.04 and doesn't apply to any other version.

Comment: You could patch now by using the -proposed repository, with the obvious downside that the packages are not yet well tested.

Comment: The `linux` package that you're refering to points to a list of  4.4.0 modules and 4.4 kernel.  That only means all ubuntu versions with that kernel version are affected.

Comment: Sorry, but that's again completely wrong. Click on the LP (Launchpad) link for the 'linux' kernel and then scroll down - you'll see that 4.4.0-21 is just the most current released version - the original kernel (before updates) from 16.04 Xenail.

If you scroll further down the list you'll see it then lists all the various versions from current releases - 4.6.0 for upcoming 16.10, 4.2 for Wily and so on.

Comment: The 'Ubuntu' link (to the packages.ubuntu.com website) above the table shows it even clearer - it lists the various kernel packages that have 'linux' as a source:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=linux